# Apart from intent is there any other way to send data across activities in android studio

Tags: android

Intent is useful to send data from one activity to another. But I want to send data from 15 components to another activity . How can it be done?? Do I need to write putExtra statement 15 times?

Comment: You can use objects that are saved in the application context, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Application;

public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

    //Used to pass data between activity components.

  private Object universalObject = null;//Can be any type at all


  public void setUniversalObject(Object a) {
    this.universalObject = a;
  }

  public Object getUniversalObject() {
    return a;
  }
}
```

You then get the object by calling `((ExampleApplication)getApplication()).getUniversalObject();`