# How to declare an object at class level and get intent data?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

i'm trying to recive a ArrayList from one activity to another and then add some data to the list and then pass it along again.
The thing is, when I do this I have to declare it at class level but then my question is. How do I get the data from the intent when declaring it at class level?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Start onCreate Listan");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listan);
        Bundle listan = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<Produkt> lista = (ArrayList<Produkt>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
        if (lista.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "lista==null");
            ListProduktAdapter adapter = new ListProduktAdapter(Listan.this, lista);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            Bundle produktInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
            String name = produktInfo.getString("name").toString();
            String allergen = produktInfo.getString("allergen").toString();
            Produkt produkt = new Produkt(allergen, name);
            Log.d(TAG, "gjort produkt");
            lista.add(produkt);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        else {
            ListProduktAdapter adapter = new ListProduktAdapter(Listan.this, lista);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            Bundle produktInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
            String name = produktInfo.getString("name").toString();
            String allergen = produktInfo.getString("allergen").toString();
            Produkt produkt = new Produkt(allergen, name);
            Log.d(TAG, "gjort produkt");
            lista.add(produkt);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Here is the method where I will pass it along again.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Scanning Failed");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Scannad");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, getXML.class);
            i.putExtra("barCode", result.getContents());
            i.putExtra("list", lista);
            startActivity(i);
            Log.d(TAG, "Going to new activity");
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

The error I get is that it "can't resolve symbol 'lista'" on the i.putExtra("list", lista);
On the "onActivityResult"

## Solved:

I solved the problem by initiating the object in mainactivity and passing it through the flow of activities as empty until I started adding data to it.

Comment: what error is occured?

Comment: Check the answer I gave here, it might be useful in your case [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878434/apart-from-intent-is-there-any-other-way-to-send-data-across-activities-in-andro/37878718#37878718).

Comment: @VishalPatoliya The error is that on the onActivityResult it can't find "lista" when i.putExtra.

Comment: @CoolGuyCG Will give it a try, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

***You can use Java Interfaces for this. But if you want to use a approach with less complexity you can also use the following method.***

Instead declaring two separate Activity files, you can declare activity file inside a activity class file. Such as

```
public class Outerclass{

   //instance method of the outer class 
   void my_Method(){
      int num = 23;

      //method-local inner class
      class MethodInner_Demo{
         public void print(){
            System.out.println("This is method inner class "+num);     
         }   
      }//end of inner class

      //Accessing the inner class
      MethodInner_Demo inner = new MethodInner_Demo();
      inner.print();
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Outerclass outer = new Outerclass();
      outer.my_Method();           
   }
}
```

Just like that you can declare two activities in a single file and can also pass data from one another with ease.

And for declaring in the manifest use following approach:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.foo.OuterActivity$InnerActivity" ></activity>
```

But you will have to decalre the innerClass as Static using

```
public static class InnerActivity{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstand your question, but why do you declare

```
`ArrayList<Produkt> lista = (ArrayList<Produkt>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");`
```

inside onCreate() ?

You are declaring the variable inside the onCreate() method instead of as a class member instance.

Comment: The thing is, the first time I get to this activity the list do not yet exist. So I want to create it in this activty then pass is back to the previus activity then pass is to this actity again and add more data to it.
Or if I could save the data in the list even tho I change activity so I don't have to pass it back and forth.